# how to generate ireport when put value jtextfield then hit button java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

First of all I am a beginner at using jasper ireport and I am trying to generate a jasper ireport when a user is putting a value in a jtextfield, and then pressing a button, it should generate a report in PDF for Invoice. This is the first time I am using java netbeans with jasper ireport.

So how do I generate an ireport when the user have put its value in the jtextfield and then pressed a button, where it then should generate a invoice report in PDF, using java netbeans?

I have created an invoice in ireport 4.7.1 and posted the code below for the print button regardign the invoice, but when I hit the button it loads all invoices located in my project.

```
String invreport = "C:\\Users\\Silent Heart\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SIS\\src\\reports\\invoice.jrxml";
            JasperReport jpr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(invreport);
            JasperPrint jpp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jpr, null,conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jpp);
```

This is a snapshot of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: hello no one is there to help me on my issue ?
plz need help.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem.

First add parameter like `" testid "` in jasper ireport parameter area then add this parameter in query of your database in jasper ireport like

```
"select * from test where id = $P{testid}"
```

then add below code for button:

```
//              parameter
                    String para = txt1.getText();

                    //load report location
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("\\src\\test\\report1.jrxml");
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                    //set parameters
                    Map map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("testid", para);

                    //compile report
                    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JasperCompileManager.compileReport(bufferedInputStream);
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, conn);


                    //view report to UI
                        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

for PDF use `"  JasperExportManager "`

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks..